# Is there any way to make a button do something on the first press and something else on the second press in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was currently working on an app and have made it so when I press the continue button it shows the image with a .toggle() but on the second time p press it I want it to change to a blank screen is there any way to do this or am I going to have to add a second button to change to a blank canvas.

Comment: Yes, you maintain a state variable to know what action the button should perform

Comment: I am new to swift and have no idea on how to do that. Should I make a if{ } else { } statement for the button. if you could please help me out that would be much appreciated here is my code: https://pastebin.com/pzv1m2sq

Comment: @Zoren Please, include your code in the question, as much as simplified as possible but in a way that it is still able to show the issue. Questions must be "complete" so that thay can be useful to other people than you in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use state pattern here.

First create `enum` with all button states

```
enum ButtonState {
    case notTapped, tappedOnce
}
```

Then create a property in a class that handle button tap

```
var buttonState: ButtonState = .notTapped
```

Now you can handle button tap in a way you want

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    switch buttonState {
    case .notTapped:
        print("do something")
        buttonState = .tappedOnce
    case .tappedOnce:
        print("do something again")
    }
}
```

You can add any states you want and handle them as you want

Comment: How would I add that to an existing scrip would I put in The vstack or outside of the struct?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience working with SwiftUI framework. enum ca be put inside or outside the struct (in the first case he will be visible only inside that struct).
State property and action handler should be added in scope of your struct/class

Comment: Thank you anyways !

Answer (score 0):

You can set different targets to the button according to it's state and toggle them in the action methods as shown below.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // write your code here
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonTappedDuringPrimaryMode(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
    
@objc ButtonTappedDuringPrimaryMode(sender: UIButton) {
    // write your code here
    sender.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonTappedDuringSecondaryMode(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
    
@objc ButtonTappedDuringSecondaryMode(sender: UIButton) {
    // write your code here
    sender.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonTappedDuringPrimaryMode(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```